# ActiveMQ doesn't open default port when launching

Tags: activemq-classic

I've got a problem with configuring ActiveMQ 5.12.0. I'm using this in `/conf/activemq.xml`:

```xml
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
<transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
<transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
<transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

However, when I use `netstat` I don't see the default port, e.g.:

```
[a@server conf]# netstat -tulpn | grep 24001
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38173           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24001/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34760           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24001/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1099            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24001/java
```

Here's some log from launching (`activemq.log`):

```
2021-03-04 20:54:06,211 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@a4753e8f: startup date [Thu Mar 04 20:54:06 MSK 2021]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2021-03-04 20:54:07,079 | INFO  | PListStore:[/opt/activemq/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | main
2021-03-04 20:54:07,116 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: JDBCPersistenceAdapter(org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@5772428d) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2021-03-04 20:54:07,153 | INFO  | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi | org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext | JMX connector
2021-03-04 20:54:07,457 | INFO  | Database adapter driver override recognized for : [oracle_jdbc_driver] - adapter: class org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.OracleJDBCAdapter | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | main
2021-03-04 20:54:07,693 | INFO  | Database lock driver override not found for : [oracle_jdbc_driver].  Will use default implementation. | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | main
2021-03-04 20:54:07,695 | INFO  | Attempting to acquire the exclusive lock to become the Master broker | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
```

Any firewalls & iptables are turned off. I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9.

Comment: What is the full startup log, you've shown just enough to make it ambiguous if the broker fully started or is running as a secondary.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I was trying to make cluster 1 active mq instance +1 tomcat app on two different servers.
When I turned off activemq my first activemq instance, second run just perfectly. Gonna find a way to make a cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what little you've provided it sounds like you currently have a set of brokers that are running using a shared store configuration meaning one will start as master and the other will start and go into standby awaiting the master going down either due to failure or from some administrative action.

I think what you are looking to create is a network of brokers (at least again from the little detail you've provided).  This requires configuration of network connectors between brokers so that messages can flow from one to the other.  This setup is documented on the ActiveMQ website [here](https://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers).